# How execute command shell content cd [repository] ls in android programmaticaly

Tags: android, shell

I need excute adb shell in android device contente cd ["repository"] + ls in Android programmaticaly ,

Exemple :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd data && cd data && cd condor.savtest && cd files && ls");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

thank you

Comment: You could just use `ls data/data/condor.savtest/files`. But I'd suggest to use java to list files in a directory instead.

Comment: i need copy txt file to other repository Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd data && cd data && cd condor.savtest && cd files && cp file.txt /system");

Comment: `cp data/data/condor.savtest/files/file.txt /system`... But that won't work without root privileges.

Comment: it has not fontionne

Comment: Root privileges are required to copy files to `/system`. If you don't have root privileges, you just can't copy to that folder.

Comment: It doesn't mean that you have root privileges. Your application must declare root permissions in the manifest, and the user must give you permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The [Runtime.exec()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[])) family of methods expect, in one way or another, the command you are trying to execute and its arguments.

In your case, you are trying to execute a shell command line. However, I guess your intention is to list the files in a directory, so in such case you should use [File.listFiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()).

Comment: i need copy txt file to other repository Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd data && cd data && cd condor.savtest && cd files && cp file.txt /system");